# Call another constructor from constructor after other instructions

Tags: java, constructor

I have 2 constructors, accepting different types of arguments:

```
public Board(String s) {

    // the string is parsed to an int array.
    int[] array = doSomething(s);

    this(array);
}

public Board(int[] array) {
    doSomethingElse(s);
}
```

However on the first constructor I get "Constructor call must be the first statement in a constructor". Is there a way to have a constructor call another after performing other actions, or is it simply a limitation of Java?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot call the constructor after doing something else in another constructor. Constructor is very special method in Java. However you have two options:

#### 1. If everything you want to do before calling another constructor is to preprocess parameters, you can write like this:

```
public Board(String s) {
    this(doSomething(s));
}

private static int[] doSomething(String s) {...}
```

You can call any static methods and pass their results to another constructor.

#### 2. If your preprocessing implies modification of current object, so you cannot do this with static methods, you can call the special method (like `init()` from both constructors):

```
public Board(String s) {
    int[] array = doSomething(s);

    init(array);
}

public Board(int[] array) {
    init(array);
}

private void init(int[] array) {
    // do something else
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As a rule of `Java`, `this` should be called first:

```
public Board(String s) {
    this(doSomething(s));
}
```

Comment: @Ramesh-X it does, if doSomething() is static.

Comment: Should or must?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't have to be a constructor. You can do like:

```
public Board(String s) {

    // the string is parsed to an int array.
    int[] array = doSomething(s);

    this.sharedMethod(array);
}

public Board(int[] array) {
    this.sharedMethod(array);
}

public void sharedMethod() {
 //yourLogic
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes in java when you call constructor from another constructor then the constructor call should be the first statement. Look at the following code snippet and the comments -

```
public class Board{

   //no-argument consturctor
   public Board(){
         //if the 'Board' class has a super class
        //then the super class constructor is called from here
       //and it will be the firs statement
       //the call can be explicit or implicit

      //Now do something
   } 

  public Board(int size){
     //call to no-arg constructor 

     this(); // explicit call to the no-argument constructor - 'Board()'
     //Now you can do something
     //but after doing something you can not 
     //make an explicit/implicit constructor call.
  }
}
```

Comment: Should or must? It must, right? You have no option.